# Disable TreeSitter highlighting in inactive buffers

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, buffers, plugin-treesitter

How can I disable TreeSitter highlighting in inactive buffers?

I currently have all inactive buffers blurred and their syntax disabled, but I can't figure out how to disable the TreeSitter highlighting.

[image]

Comment: cross-posted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/x1z926/is_there_a_way_to_disable_treesitter_highlighting/